# UseDotNet@2 task fails to pull .net 6 SDk - Azure pipelines

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I am trying to build a .Net 6 application using `UseDotNet@2` azure devops task. But the task is failing with below error.

```
 pool:
   vmImage: windows-2019


- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Use .NET 
  inputs: 
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: 6.x
    vsVersion: 17.0.x
```

[image]

But same task is able to pull preview version of .Net 6 when I specify IncludePreviewVersions as true.

[image]

Has any one faced this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported to use .NET 6 on the Windows 2019 image. Probably preview versions are more lenient than releases.

To solve the issue, explicitly select `windows-2022` as the version . Of course, if there's no explicit reason to use a Windows based build agent, you can also use an Ubuntu based build agent. If you do not specify an image for a YAML build pipeline, it will use `ubuntu-latest` by default.

For more information, see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6907)

Comment: awesome, let me try windows-latest. we need windows agent as there are lot of other windows dependent tasks in the pipeline.

Comment: windows-latest is still pulling windows-2019, but specifying the pool to windows-2022 worked for me. Thank you for your help. Please update the answer to use windows-2022 also. I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Answer has been updated.